# Список в python

Tags: python

Я беру данные из бд и мне нужно как-то занести их в список(массив)
и потом надо сделать кортеж по n элементов
[image: здесь показан результат вывода из бд и код]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Код надо показывать обычным текстом, а не картинкой. 2. Покажите данные, которые вы получаете в результате `cursor.fetchall()`. 3. Покажите что вы хотите получить.

Comment: c помощью cursor.fetchall() хочу получить данные results=['1','2' ...]

Comment: Просто уберите весь этот странный цикл и получите список/последовательность кортежей в results

Answer (score 0):

```
new_arr = [i[1:-2].split(", ") for i in arr]
```

`i[1:-2]` убираем скобки слева и справа

`split` разделяет строку по разделителю

```
new_arr = [i[1:-2].split(", ") for i in arr]
```

тоже самое что:

```
new_arr = [] 
for i in arr:
    new_arr.append(i[1:-2].split(", "))
```

Comment: вот массив  после вывода в переменную results :["(1, '89609105022 ', 'проспект Ленина ', '2012-02-12')", "(2, '89558741234 ', 'ул. Мира ', '2006-05-13')"] и получается,что ваш метод не работает

Comment: @dahal07 что именно нужно сделать, можно пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: это выходные данные после выполнения запроса, то есть,что получается при использовании cursor.fetchall()::["(1, '89609105022 ', 'проспект Ленина ', '2012-02-12')", "(2, '89558741234 ', 'ул. Мира ', '2006-05-13')"]. Мне надо,чтобы из этого сделал кортеж по 4 элемента (1, '89609105022 ', 'проспект Ленина ', '2012-02-12), (2, '89558741234 ', 'ул. Мира ', '2006-05-13')

Comment: @dahal07 все сделал

Comment: можете объяснить эту конструкцию ? чтобы понимать как она работает

Comment: Это же просто результат `results[item] = str(results[item])`, не нужно с ним бороться, нужно его убрать)